# Can't bring NIC up manually

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter, opensuse

I can't bring a 10Gb interface up with any of the commands ip link/ifconfig/ifup

```
$ ip -d link show em1
8: em1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether b8:ca:3a:62:6c:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64

$ ip link set dev em1 up
$ ifconfig em1 up
$ ifup em1
$ ip -d link show em1
8: em1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether b8:ca:3a:62:6c:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64

$ lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 (rev 01)
```

It's openSUSE Leap 42.3 and kernel 4.4.87-25-default

Comment: "NO-CARRIER" means the hardware can't detect that it's connected to anything. The problem can be in (1) whatever the card is connected to, (2) cable and connection, (3) hardware defect in card, (4) driver bug. Try to check for each.

Comment: I checked with the infra team of my company and they saw the cable disconnected. After plugging it again, the interface came up automatically. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the messages log for details on why the interface does not go up.
Please share the configuration file of cet interface.
Also, please check if that ethernet controller model supports your OS.

## PLEASE BE CAREFUL, IF OTHER INTERFACES ON YOUR MACHINE ARE USING THE SAME DRIVER THEY WILL GO DOWN IF YOU ISSUE THE `rmmod` COMMAND.

IF you suspect a driver issue, you should find out the driver name of that interface:

```
ethtool -i em1
```

The driver name will be in the "driver:" field
Then reload that specific driver:

```
rmmod <intel-driver-name-from-above-command>

modprobe <intel-driver-name-from-above-command>
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint! It was a problem of physical cabling.